# Declaring a set of member functions by a template of a function type

Tags: c++17, msvc-2017

This is simplified version of existind code, an interface for a message processing declared independant from definitions of messages:

```
/**
 * @file msg_io.h
 */
struct MsgIO { virtual ~MsgIO() {} };

/**
 * @file handler.h
 */
#include <map>
#include "msg_io.h"

template<class _msgHandler>
struct HandlerInterface 
{
    using HandlerFunc = bool (int, const MsgIO& );
    using HandlerFuncPtr = HandlerFunc _msgHandler::*;

    template<class T> using AcceptFunc = bool(int, const T*);
    template<class T> using AcceptFuncPtr = AcceptFunc<T> _msgHandler::*;

    using HandlerMap = std::map<unsigned, HandlerFuncPtr>;
};
```

Implementation:

```
/**
 * @file server.h
 */  
#include "handler.h"
struct ConcreteHandler : HandlerInterface<ConcreteHandler>
{
    enum Messages { MSG_1, MSG_2, MSG_3 };

    // Is this a compliant declaration?
    // can this be part of template?
    AcceptFunc<struct Msg1> accept;
    AcceptFunc<struct Msg2> accept;
    AcceptFunc<struct Msg3> accept;

    template<class T>
    bool acceptMsg(int ind, const MsgIO& m)
    {
        auto mp = dynamic_cast<const T*>(&m);
        return mp ? accept(ind, mp) : false;
    }

    static HandlerMap handlers;

    template<class T>
    static const constexpr HandlerFuncPtr Handle = &ConcreteHandler::acceptMsg<T>;
};
```

Messages and map of functions are declared later:

```
/**
 * @file messages.h
 */
#include "msg_io.h"  

struct Msg1: MsgIO {};
struct Msg2: MsgIO {};
struct Msg3: MsgIO {};

/**
 * @file handlermap.cpp
 */
#include "server.h"
#include "messages.h"  
// can this be made constexpr?
 ConcreteHandler::HandlerMap ConcreteHandler::handlers{
    { MSG_1,        Handle<Msg1> },
    { MSG_2,        Handle<Msg2> },
    { MSG_3,        Handle<Msg3> },
    { MSG_10,       Handle<Msg1> }
};

/**
 * @file handler.cpp
 */
#include "server.h"
#include "messages.h"  

bool ConcreteHandler::accept(int, const Msg1*) { return true; }
bool ConcreteHandler::accept(int, const Msg2*) { return true; }
bool ConcreteHandler::accept(int, const Msg3*) { return true; }
```

So `ConcreteHandler::handlers::find()` can get pointer to correct `acceptMsg` function based on some integer value (message number from stream, etc).

Question:
How can it be turned into a declaration of an interface looking something like  `AcceptFunctions<Msg1, Msg2, Msg3>::accept` along with `AcceptFunctions<Msg1, Msg2, Msg3>::handlers`? Can the map be initializated at compile time as `constexpr`?

Comment: @billz there are no virtual interfaces here, only static ones.  message got a virtual base (originally it's a protobuf class)

Comment: Are you familiar with template packs? `template<typename T...>` ?It's fairly obvious that `ConcreteHandler::accept` can have only one type.

Comment: Also, you may be reinventing `std::visit`. Given a `std::variant<Msg1, Msg2, Msg3> msg;` which holds a message of unspecified type, `std::visit(myConcreteHandler, msg)` will call `ConcreteHandler::operator()(Msg1)`, `operator()(Msg2)` or `operator()(Msg3)`.

Comment: @MSalters `std:visit` is while is named after Visitor template  but  works with variant type. I don't have a fixed variant. Instead I have a stream (~200 different types for several consumers, 15-20 per consumer). Plus there is a usual problem that MSVC as usual is a broken compiler with incoherent behaviour while GCC is not, I can't figure out to use template pack to implement all `accepts`. It may be convoluted butrequrements of who demands it to have single site of specifying what takes which without having, I quote, "scary templates" (this is just an altered fragment of it)

Comment: @MSalters their solution is to write array  (a badly written and non-compliant) container type with a mutex in global space, and add  that to each project\module (~1200 variables, all appear to be instanced by compier, 196kb each).so their code just iterates through them all by array of pointers. My code just gets rid of that and leaves only what project requires.

Comment: There is no strict on-one equivalence too, for example there can be `MSG_1` , `struct Msg1` and `MSG_40` `struct Msg1`, same type of message in-stream, but differnt id, which denotes related object. (in all honesty,I rathre re-invent `asio` and SCADA, but no librares are present on the platform)

Comment: MSVC has been handling template packs well enough since VS2013, from personal experience (I implemented something similar). You tag it C++17, but this is basic C++11 stuff. As for "no libraries present on platform", well, you ship your own code. Just include Boost or whatever, and don't assume it's already present.

Comment: @MSalters eh, if it's an ISA that isn't widely used, so I would need to _port_ boost.  It appears MSVC doesn't support `using` parameter pack extension

Comment: That's [fixed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/pack-expansion-in-using-declarations-fails-with-te/338188). But why MSVC? It's not supporting obscure ISA's.

Comment: @MSalters eh.. reasons.. mostly because I'm only one who can write code without IDE and compile it in console :P